# Почему ResultSet методы выбрасывают SQL исключения?

Tags: jdbc, java, sql

```
ResultSet rs = ....
```

пишу я строку

```
rs.beforeFirst();
```

и тут , IDE заставляет меня обработать **SQLException**. Почитав доки, я понял что *ResultSet* инкапсулирует результат запроса, но почему его методы обязаны кидать исключения связанные со связью с БД(методы не только написанные выше) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ResultSet` - это интерфейс

Доступ к данным зависит от его реализации, потому вполне возможна ситуация когда придётся добывать дополнительные параметры из БД при вызове методов из интерфейса *ResultSet*.
Если при запросе к БД возникли проблемы, то логично кинуть исключение *SQLException*.

Методы могут и ни кидать исключение, но это интерфейс и те кто его делали подумали что для каких-то СУБД возможно исключение в любом месте.

Ну и реализация JDBC заставляет работать через интерфейсы взамен конкретным классам (для единообразной работы со всеми СУБД).